# Launch Linux graphical application from a terminal with "exec" command behaviour

Tags: linux, terminal, window-managers

I am using i3-wm on Linux, and I am trying to imitate the behaviour of a program launcher. I already know about the "exec" command, which seems to work as expected for non-graphical commands.

For example, if I type in a terminal:

`exec sudo ls -aR`

I will get a list of all folders and files of the current directory. When the command exits, the terminal disappears.

But if I type instead in a terminal:

`exec chromium-browser`

I will end up with two windows: one being chromium; the other one being the terminal that launched chromium, now used by chromium to print debug info.

How can I start i.e. chromium-browser from a terminal and keep it alive while hiding or killing the terminal that launched it?

Comment: I wonder why you think your 2 test cases are different. They're doing the exact same thing. In one case, the terminal is waiting for `sudo ls ...` to finish. In the other case, it's waiting for `chromium-browser` to finish. The only difference is that one of those things typically happens faster.

Comment: In the `chromium-browser` case, a new window pops-up. In the `sudo ls` case, the same window is used.

Comment: Of course the commands do different things, but their relationship to the parent process is identical. Processes and windows aren't tied together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to start a graphical application in background ("&") and then "disown" it, like that:

`chromium-browser & disown`

In my case, I have to kill the terminal after doing so:

`chromium-browser & disown && exit`

*Note the use of "&&" instead of ";". If disowning no job, then not exiting.*

By the way, in my case, I found that making an alias `x` having `disown && exit` as value could come in handy. If I want to start a graphical application from the terminal, then this is how I do it:

`chromium-browser &x`

I just thought mentioning this could maybe help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to disown the chromium-browser process. To do this, you could use the nohup command such as `nohup chromium-browser &`. Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10547/how-to-clean-launch-a-gui-app-via-the-terminal-so-it-doesnt-wait-for-terminati) for more information.

Comment: I just tried it, and I still had to keep the terminal open to keep chromium open. If I kill the terminal, chromium gets killed too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for stating about disowning a process. It made me seek deeper into the good direction.